# RewriteCond dynamic to static url doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i try to change my current URL:

www.mypage.de/?section=messages&sub=received

to this url:

www.mypage.de/messages/received

i tried this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule $1/(.*)/ /?section=$1
</IfModule>
```

but without effect.

thanks fabian